# Android: Gridview not smooth scrollable when first launch, and hangs when loading another class

Tags: android, image, gridview

I have created a gridview with around 100 images by following the example in http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-implementing-viewpager-into-gridview-tutorial/

There is a gridview index page showing thumbnails of 100 images, and when clicking the thumbnails, it will go to ImageViewer page showing image with fit-screen size.

### Code:

### Index_Gridview.java

```
gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);      // Set the images from ImageAdapter.java to GridView
gridview .setFastScrollEnabled(true);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    // Listening to GridView item click
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        {                               
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageViewPager.class);   // Launch ImageViewPager.java on selecting GridView Item             
            i.putExtra("id", position); // Send the click position to ImageViewPager.java using intent
            startActivity(i);   // Start ImageViewPager
        }
    });
```

### ImageAdapter.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null)                    // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        {   
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        }
        else 
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // References to our images in res > drawable
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = 
        {
            R.drawable.A, 
            R.drawable.B, 
                    ...
        }
```

### ImageViewPager.java

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.picture_previewer);        // Get the view from view_pager.xml

        saved_position = ImageViewPager.this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);

        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
        Intent p = getIntent();
        position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");

        vocab_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vocab_array); 

        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        // Retrieve all the images
        for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) 
        {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER); 
            images.add(imageView);            
        }

        ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images); // Set the images into ViewPager
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(position); // Show images following the position
    }
```

### ImagePagerAdapter.java

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
{
    private List<ImageView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) 
    {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
        ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) 
    {
        return view == o;
    }
}
```

### Question:

The code can be run, yet there are 2 problems:

1. For the first time loading the gridview index page, the page can be scrolled but cannot scroll down smoothly, but when going to `ImageViewer` class and then coming back to show back the gridview index, the index page can scroll **extremely smooth**.
2. When going to the `ImageViewer` page, it will go blank screen and hang for 5 seconds and then suddenly it can load out the full-size image.

What is going on and how could that be modified? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post you ImageViewer.class? The root cause of the issue #2 has to be in this class

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I have posted also the `ImageViewPager` class, thanks!

Comment: ImagePagerAdapter.class also might be necessary... Do you debug your application to find line(-s), which takes 5 seconds to execute?

Comment: thanks! ImagePagerAdapter class is also added. The logcat process shows that it has skipped many frames as the `imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);` had involved too much works...and now it starts to pop out `outofmemoryerror`...I am trying to add those `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource` lines to see if that can solve the issues..

Comment: Are you using .png images? What is the size of your images? Maybe you should think about reducing images size.

Comment: yes using .png images with size 400x400px, around each 150kb. Yet since phone screen dimension is greater than 400x400px, for a full screen imageview the image is a bit blur already (quality thumbnail in the gridview index is ok) I really would like to know how other apps can do so without utilizing much resources? To load only the image that is on the screen (i.e. load one by one?)

Comment: Btw, what about onResume/onStart code in your ImageViewer.class? Do you use some heavy stuff in these methods?

Comment: ummm just to load a TTS, nothing more~ is it proper for viewpager to view 150 images just working like the one shown in http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-implementing-viewpager-into-gridview-tutorial/?

Comment: Could you try remove/comment all code in onCreate/onResume/OnStart that doesn't relate to viewpager functionality and try? I think, that delay can occur because of tts initialization

Comment: yes I have tried...seems TTS demands not much resources..the core problem occurs at line `imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);` and it now keeps on popping out `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`...

Comment: Thanks for your continous help!  I hv managed to increase the performance by modifying the codes:  the images should not all be loaded in the imageviewpager activity.  It should only fetch the required image in the adapter instead.